# Extracting information from R list

Tags: r

This is follow up of my previous question where I was trying to download the options data from yahoo finance. It still does not work. But I found another code on internet which works but output is in a format I am not able to work with as I am a bit new to R.

The code gives me a variable called OptionPrices.

Following is the output of OptionPrices which prints using command fix(OptionPrices) as:

---

```
structure(list(call = structure(list(Strike = 26, Symbol = structure(1L, .Label = "VIXM131221C00026000", class = "factor"), 
    Last = 1.8, Chg = 0, Bid = 2.05, Ask = 2.65, Vol = 10L, Open.Int = 10L), .Names = c("Strike", 
"Symbol", "Last", "Chg", "Bid", "Ask", "Vol", "Open.Int"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame"), put = structure(list(Strike = c(24, 
25, 26, 29), Symbol = structure(1:4, .Label = c("VIXM131221P00024000", 
"VIXM131221P00025000", "VIXM131221P00026000", "VIXM131221P00029000"
), class = "factor"), Last = c(1.05, 2, 3.2, 4.3), Chg = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), Bid = c(1, 1.45, 1.95, 3.8), Ask = c(1.4, 1.85, 2.35, 
4.4), Vol = c(20L, 1L, 10L, 10L), Open.Int = c(20L, 5L, 10L, 
10L)), .Names = c("Strike", "Symbol", "Last", "Chg", "Bid", "Ask", 
"Vol", "Open.Int"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"), 
    Stock.ticker = "VIXM", Quote.date = <S4 object of class structure("timeDate", package = "timeDate")>, 
    Strike.date = <S4 object of class structure("timeDate", package = "timeDate")>, 
    Stock.name = "ProShares VIX Mid-Term Futures ETF (VIXM)", 
    Stock.price = 26.34, TTM = 193, Short.rate = 0.0893939393939394), .Names = c("call", 
"put", "Stock.ticker", "Quote.date", "Strike.date", "Stock.name", 
"Stock.price", "TTM", "Short.rate"))
```

---

The yahoo finance page from where the above information is extracted is:

http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=VIXM&m=2013-12

I want to create vectors for strikes, option symbols, the bid price, the ask price, etc. from the above variable OptionPrices.

How do I achieve that.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example. How are we supposed to figure out what's wrong without knowing the code you used?

Comment: Copy/pasting your `dput` ouput results in error. Did you check it yourself?

Comment: Where did I write anything is wrong. All I am asking is how to read it. Please read carefully before putting negative vote.

Comment: @Arun I just copied and pasted my output from R. All I want is some guide on how to read such a list to create vectors out of it. Thanks

Comment: @Zanam Try typing the following at the console (one at a time): `OptionPrices$call` `OptionPrices$put` `OptionPrices$Stock.ticker` `OptionPrices$Quote.date` `OptionPrices$Strike.date` `OptionPrices$Stock.name` `OptionPrices$Stock.price` `OptionPrices$TTM` `OptionPrices$Short.rate`. Just type them directly, do not use `fix` or `dput`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't quite get your code to work, even if I load the R package `timeDate`.
But, once I got rid of the `Stock.date` and `Quote.date` parts, I was able to see what you are being given.

```
OptionPrices <- structure(list(call = structure(list(Strike = 26, Symbol = structure(1L, .Label = "VIXM131221C00026000", class = "factor"), 
    Last = 1.8, Chg = 0, Bid = 2.05, Ask = 2.65, Vol = 10L, Open.Int = 10L), .Names = c("Strike", 
    "Symbol", "Last", "Chg", "Bid", "Ask", "Vol", "Open.Int"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), put = structure(list(Strike = c(24, 
    25, 26, 29), Symbol = structure(1:4, .Label = c("VIXM131221P00024000", 
    "VIXM131221P00025000", "VIXM131221P00026000", "VIXM131221P00029000"
    ), class = "factor"), Last = c(1.05, 2, 3.2, 4.3), Chg = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0), Bid = c(1, 1.45, 1.95, 3.8), Ask = c(1.4, 1.85, 2.35, 
    4.4), Vol = c(20L, 1L, 10L, 10L), Open.Int = c(20L, 5L, 10L, 
    10L)), .Names = c("Strike", "Symbol", "Last", "Chg", "Bid", "Ask", 
    "Vol", "Open.Int"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"), 
    Stock.ticker = "VIXM", Stock.name = "ProShares VIX Mid-Term Futures ETF (VIXM)", 
    Stock.price = 26.34, TTM = 193, Short.rate = 0.0893939393939394), .Names = c("call", 
    "put", "Strike.date", "Stock.name", 
    "Stock.price", "TTM", "Short.rate"))
```

So, `OptionPrices` is a list, and it appears that you are interested in the information contained in the `put` element. 
You can save this element to a data frame, then access each element (vector) of the data frame using either the names or the column numbers.

```
df <- OptionPrices$put
df$Last
df[, 3]
```